# How can I do a http.request using a different gateway?

Tags: node.js

I have one network connection on my Macbook Pro. It is configured by my ADSL modem by DHCP. That modem is on 192.168.1.1 . I also have a cable modem connected to the network. I switched its DHCP server off. It is on 192.168.1.254 .

How can I connect to a URL using the cable modem?

I think I have to set up a vlan which I then can use by setting the localAddress option of http.request. Am I right?

Comment: what do you mean by "a URL"? do you mean a website like "google.com" also what are you trying to use vlans for?

Comment: Actually I do not know what vlans are. I found the solution in making another interface on the same physical interface using the network settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out that it is not possible with one ethernet interface. So I bought another usb to ethernet adapter. Now one is configured by DHCP. The other is configured by hand. In node I use the localAddress to set which interface to use.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Somebody has to